# Can pbpaste access screen capture pasteboard on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, shell

On Mac OSX, user does: cmd-option-shift-4 to capture screen to pasteboard (clipboard). Which pasteboard is this stored in? Can it be accessed by `pbpaste`?

command line tool `pbpaste` allows access of the pasteboard. I tried all the variations of this command and never generated output from the screen capture (but, if I paste into Preview, the screen capture is outputted).

```
pbpaste [-help] [-pboard {general | ruler | find | font}] [-Prefer {txt | rtf | ps}]
```

I tried each permutation of -pboard and -Prefer values with no luck.

Intended use would be a script like this:

bash script:

```
#/bin/bash
pbpaste > /tmp/tmp.png
tesseract /tmp/tmp.png /tmp/tmp -l eng #open source ocr tool
cat /tmp/tmp.txt                       #tool adds .txt
```

**EDIT:**

The answer I accepted is true, for the command `pbpaste`. But, I found what I am looking for. A command called pngpaste. I installed this via brew, in case anyone else ends up needing it.

So, my ocr from the png clipboard works like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste
pngpaste /tmp/tmp.png

#open source ocr tool
tesseract /tmp/tmp.png /tmp/tmp -l eng

#tesseract adds .txt
cat /tmp/tmp.txt | pbcopy
```

Comment: You should add the content at the end of your post to a new ‘answer’; answering your own posts is something that is allowed, and encouraged, on Stack Overflow (and will allow us to vote it up, and link directly to it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `pbpaste` can only retrieve plain text, EPS, or RTF data from the pasteboard. A screenshot is none of those types, so `pbpaste` cannot access it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there command line tool that you know of that can access the screenshot? Do you know what type it is? I can't find a good write up on the pasteboard system / types.

Answer (score 2):

For @ELLIOTTCABLE :)

---

The answer I accepted is true, for the command pbpaste. But, I found what I am looking for. A command called pngpaste. I installed this via brew, in case anyone else ends up needing it.

So, my ocr from the png clipboard works like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste
pngpaste /tmp/tmp.png

#open source ocr tool
tesseract /tmp/tmp.png /tmp/tmp -l eng

#tesseract adds .txt
cat /tmp/tmp.txt | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

It seems, from your question and comments, that the general idea of what you are trying to do is this:

- Mark an area of the screen
- OCR it
- Place OCR'ed text into Clipboard

If we go into more detail... you want to copy the area of the screen to the Clipboard, paste it into a file in `/tmp`, run `tesseract`, and put the tesseract output into the Clipboard.

Now, that is not going to work because , as @duskwuff says, `pbpaste` doesn't support graphics, so your problem now becomes, presumably, how to get a screencapture to a file without using `pbpaste`. As I see it, you have two options...

**Option 1**

Write a script that calls `screencapture` and captures the screen to a file and OCRs that. The script would look like:

```
#/bin/bash
screencapture -i /tmp/tmp.png
tesseract /tmp/tmp.png /tmp/tmp -l eng
pbcopy < /tmp/tmp.txt
```

**Option 2**

Write a script that continually monitors `/tmp` for new screen captures and when a new one arrives, OCR it and stuff it in the Clipboard. To use this method, you would want to use the two commands in my original answer to force all screen captures to go to `/tmp`. Your script would then look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
fswatch /tmp | while read file; do tesseract ...; pbcopy < ...; done
```

The main difference between these two methods is how they are invoked. Option 1 requires you to run a script or double click a script to start the capture process. Option 2 requires you to simply press cmd-option-shift-4 and mark the screen and then the OCR happens automatically.

**Original Answer**

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but you can make screenshots get saved in /tmp as a PNG by issuing these two commands;

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type png
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /tmp
```

You will need to restart the GUI after making these changes

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: What is the point of this? The question is about a screenshot that's already been taken and is in the pasteboard, not saved to file. If you're going to take a screenshot from a script or at the command line, just use the `screencapture` tool, possibly in interactive (`-i`) mode.

Comment: The script example in my question actually shows about half of what I'm trying to do. I want to take a screen shot using cmd-option-shift-4 and then run a command line script which will ocr the image and then dump the orc'd text onto the text clipboard. I have all the pieces except the ability to access the image clipboard (if that's what its called) from the command line.

Comment: @KenThomases I have updated my answer to try and clarify what the point is.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I found what I am looking for: pngpaste command. It has access to the PNG clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for updating on the solution, the pngpaste command helped me as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to access clipboard.
Modify bellow.

1. Change folder for screenshot.

   `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/screens/
   killall SystemUIServer`
2. Copy `ss2CB.plist` to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`.
3. Copy `ss2cb.py` to `~/`.
4. Test with `Cmd + Shift + 4` & Paste it!
5. Done!

ss2CB.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>copy Screen Shots to ClipBoard</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python</string>
        <string>~/ss2cb.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/screens/</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

ss2cb.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import os
import sys

def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    image = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(f)
    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    clipboard.set_image(image)
    clipboard.store()

def all_files_under(path):
    path = os.path.expanduser(path);
    cur_path = path
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        yield os.path.join(cur_path, filename)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    file = max(all_files_under('~/screens/'), key=os.path.getctime)
else:
    file = sys.argv[1]

copy_image(file);
print 'File: "' + file + '" Copied'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with fewer commands and without creating a `.txt` file:

```sh
pngpaste /tmp/tmp.png
tesseract /tmp/tmp.png - -l eng | pbcopy
```